# How to generate nonperiodic tilings?

Tags: graphics, geometry, code-request, packing

I need to generate nonperiodic tilings which are similar to the attached figure (kite-domino tiling). I was thinking the code is similar to the code for the Penrose tiling. However, that code is too complicated for me to digest at this time.

[image: Kite-Domino Tiling]

Comment: What is the specific question you are asking?  There is no question stated in your post.  For Penrose: http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~crobles/tiling/penrose/inflation.html  Code: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/554/12

Comment: I *think* the question is "I need to generate nonperiodic tilings"...

Comment: This looks to me to be a pure Tom Sawyer request. The OP seems to be saying "This problem is too hard for me, so will someone do it for me?". I say: close it as too broad.

Comment: Looking at the image and seeing there is a sub-tiling that forms a rectangle, it seems clear that a periodic tiling is possible with kite and rectangle tiles. In fact, I can see at least three different periodic tilings.

Comment: For generating self-similar non-periodic tilings, like the Penrose tiling, the simplest method is to recursively subdivide the tiles.  You'll find a lot of information on this if you search for "deflation".  For implementing this in Mathematica you can use some recursive programming, the same way e.g. Koch curves are generated.

Answer (score 27):

The kite-domino tiling is based the pinwheel tiling which is falls out of a particular decomposition of a right triangle with legs of length 1 and 2.  In the code that follows, `rt[{a,b,c}]` represents such a right triangle and `dissect` indicates how such a triangle should be decomposed into smaller copies of itself.  We simply iterate the dissect function on an initial configuration.

```
dissect[rt[{a_, b_, c_}]] := Module[
   {d, e, f, g},
   d = c + ((a - c).(b - c))/((a - c).(a - c)) (a - c) // N;
   e = (a + b)/2 // N;
   f = b + ((d - b).(e - b))/((d - b).(d - b)) (d - b) // N;
   g = a + ((e - a).(c - a))/((c - a).(c - a)) (c - a) // N;
   {rt[{a, g, e}], rt[{d, g, e}], 
    rt[{e, f, d}], rt[{e, f, b}],
    rt[{b, d, c}]}];
dissect[l_List] := dissect /@ l;
init = {rt[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}}]};
iterated = NestList[dissect, init, 2];
GraphicsColumn[Graphics[{
     {Thick, Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {0, 0}}]}, 
     # /. rt[{a_, b_, c_}] ->
       {Opacity[0.6], Line[{a, b, c, a}]}}] & /@ iterated]
```

[image]

Now, if we merely delete each hypotenuse, we already obtain something close to what you want.  We can also expand the initial configuration to include a whole rectangle.

```
init = {rt[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}}], rt[{{2, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}}]};
Graphics[Nest[dissect, init, 4] /. rt[{a_, b_, c_}] -> Line[{a, b, c}]]
```

[image]

It's trickier to distinguish the kites from the dominoes.  I'm certain there's a better way to do this, but one approach is to merge the triangles we've just generated.  This is not so simple because, often, the `a1` in `rt[{a1,b,c1}]` and the `a2` in `rt[{a2,d,c1}]` may be very close but not equal.  The following attempts to deal with that

```
Needs["HierarchicalClustering`"]
canonicalFunction[nonCanonicalValues_List] := Module[
      {heirarchy, MyClusters, segregate, cf, clusters, 
    canonicalValues},
      Quiet[heirarchy = Agglomerate[N[nonCanonicalValues],
              DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance,
              Linkage -> "Average"]];
      segregate[Cluster[cl1_, cl2_, d_, _, _], tol_] :=   
    MyClusters[cl1, cl2] /; d > tol;
      segregate[mine_MyClusters, tol_] := 
    segregate[#, tol] & /@ mine;
      segregate[x_, _] := x;
      cf[cl_Cluster] := ClusterFlatten[cl];
      cf[x_] := {x};
      clusters = cf /@ 
     List @@ Flatten[FixedPoint[segregate[#, 10^(-12)] &,
                        MyClusters[heirarchy]]];
      canonicalValues = Chop[First /@ clusters];
      toCanonical[x_] := First[Nearest[canonicalValues][x]];
      toCanonical];
pts = Partition[Flatten[iterated /. rt -> Sequence], 2];
cf = canonicalFunction[pts];
gathered = 
  GatherBy[Flatten[iterated], Sort[cf /@ {#[[1, 1]], #[[1, 3]]}] &];
preserved = Select[gathered, #[[1, 1, 1]] == #[[2, 1, 1]] &];
flipped = Select[gathered, #[[1, 1, 1]] == #[[2, 1, 3]] &];
join[{rt[{a_, b_, c_}], rt[{_, d_, _}]}] := Polygon[{a, b, c, d}];
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black],
  {Darker[Red], join /@ flipped},
  {Gray, join /@ preserved}
  }]
```

[image]

Comment: Apparently the `rt1`s end up forming *some of* the dominoes and the `rt2`s end up forming the kites *and the rest of the dominoes*.

Comment: The next step is of course to produce the 3D analog with  Quaquaversal tilling :-)