# Converting a Sierpinski tetrahedron to a Graph

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, computational-geometry, fractals

I need a representation of a [3D Sierpinski gasket](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tetrix.html) as a graph to perform some simulations on. The 2D version is included in `GraphData[]`, but the 3D one is nowhere to be found, so I was wondering if there is a way to convert `Graphics3D` objects to `Graph`s.

Say we have some geometry: (or even something as simple as `Cuboid[]`):

```
(*From Wiki =>*)
vect[1] = {0, 0, 0};
vect[2] = {1, 0, 0};
vect[3] = {0.5, 3^0.5/2, 0};
vect[4] = {0.5, 1/3*3^0.5/2, ((3^0.5/2)^2 - (1/3*3^0.5/2)^2)^0.5};
Tetron[{i_, j_, k_}] := 
  Tetrahedron[{vect[1] + {i, j, k}, vect[2] + {i, j, k}, 
    vect[3] + {i, j, k}, vect[4] + {i, j, k}}];
SiPyramid[0, {i_, j_, k_}] := {Tetron[{i, j, k}]};
SiPyramid[n_, {i_, j_, k_}] := 
  Module[{s = {}}, 
   Do[s = Union[s, 
      SiPyramid[n - 1, 2^(n - 1)*vect[u] + {i, j, k}]], {u, 4}]; s];
```

[image: tetrix]

```
b = Graphics3D[SiPyramid[2, {1, 1, 1}]];
list = Cases[b, {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ}, Infinity];
Length[list];


lattice[L_List, r_: 1] := 
  With[{d = Length[L], 
    LL = Reverse@FoldList[Times, 1, Reverse@Abs@L][[1 ;; -2]]}, 
   With[{Δ = 
      Pick[#, UnitStep[# - 1] UnitStep[r^2 - #] &@Total[#^2, {2}], 
         1] &@Tuples[Range[-#, #] &@Ceiling[r], d]}, 
    Module[{Id = 
       Join @@ Table[
            Transpose[{#, # + Δ[[i]]}, {2, 3, 1}], {i, 
             Length[Δ]}] &@Transpose@Tuples[Range /@ Abs[L]] - 
        1}, Do[If[L[[i]] > 0, 
       Id = Pick[Id, 
         UnitStep[#] UnitStep[L[[i]] - 1 - #] &@Id[[All, 2, i]], 1], 
       Id[[All, All, i]] = Mod[Id[[All, All, i]], -L[[i]]]], {i, d}];
     SparseArray[1 + Id.LL -> ConstantArray[1, Length[Id]]]]]];

AdjacencyGraph[lattice[{8, 8}, 1], VertexCoordinates -> list]
```

[image: my attempt]

This is how far I've gotten with this, but obviously some of the edge connections are wrong. Is there a more general way to perform this "conversion", or fix this method so that the links are right? Perhaps convert an .obj to a graph where vertices are nodes and edges are links?

[Link to Lattice to Adjacency Matrix Source](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35611/generating-a-graph-where-vertices-correspond-to-points-in-an-integer-lattice-and)

**UPDATE:**

The figure can also be defined as

```
TetraVec[i_] := 2 IntegerDigits[3 i - 2, 2, 3] - 1;
tetrix[-1, p_: {0, 0, 0}] := Polygon /@ Array[TetraVec[#] +
            p & /@ Delete[Range[4], #] &, 4];
tetrix[n_, p_: {0, 0, 0}] := 
  Array[tetrix[n - 1, p + TetraVec[#] 2^n] &, 4];
```

Comment: Related link, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22256/how-can-i-compile-this-function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Altho this is a modification of my previous answer, I decided to post this separately, because the strategy for removing the duplicate points (a problem also touched upon by Mark) is different. This leverages the functionality of `MeshRegion[]`, which apparently has the remarkable ability to detect and remove duplicate points. The code is now surprisingly compact and efficient:

```
tetpts = N[PolyhedronData["Tetrahedron", "VertexCoordinates"], 20];
tet = Tetrahedron[tetpts];
tr = TranslationTransform /@ (tetpts/2);

With[{n = 6}, (* ! *)
     tp = Flatten[Cases[Nest[# /. Tetrahedron[pts_] :> Map[Tetrahedron[#[pts/2]] &, tr] &,
                             tet, n], Tetrahedron[pts_] :> pts, ∞], 1];
     tm = MeshRegion[tp, Tetrahedron /@ Partition[Range[4^(n + 1)], 4]];
     Graph3D[Range[MeshCellCount[tm, 0]], UndirectedEdge @@@ (First /@ MeshCells[tm, 1]), 
             EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line", VertexCoordinates -> MeshCoordinates[tm]]]
```

[image: Sierpinski graph]

---

Here is another minimal implementation (note that the resulting tetrahedron is scaled differently from the previous one):

```
tet = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
ts = tet/2; tr = {{1, 0, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2, 0}, {1/2, 1/(2 Sqrt[3]), Sqrt[2/3]}};
With[{n = 6},
     tm = MeshRegion[Flatten[Nest[# /. mat_?MatrixQ :>
                                   (TranslationTransform[#][mat/2] & /@ ts) &, tet, n], n],
                     Tetrahedron[Partition[Range[4^(n + 1)], 4]]];
     Graph3D[Range[MeshCellCount[tm, 0]], 
             UndirectedEdge @@@ (First /@ MeshCells[tm, 1]), 
             EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line", VertexCoordinates -> MeshCoordinates[tm].tr]]
```

Comment: It makes good sense that `MeshRegion` should be able to do this. The whole point of `Mesh*` and friends is to generate triangulations suitable for work with PDEs and you need to know exactly this type of connectivity information to do so. In fact, I originally wrote my duplication elimination code for graphs precisely because I was studying PDE's on fractals.

Comment: Ah, I've seen that paper! I actually also tried this strategy on the Menger sponge after discovering `MeshRegion[]`'s ability; the resulting code was about thrice as efficient as the one that had me using clustering.

Answer (score 21):

A natural and simple way to approach this problem, assuming that your `SiPyramid` function has been defined, is as follows:

```
g = SiPyramid[1, {1, 1, 1}];
vertices = Union[g /. Tetrahedron[{vv__}] -> vv];
edges = Flatten[g /. Tetrahedron[vv_] :> 
  UndirectedEdge @@@ Subsets[vv, {2}]];
Graph3D[vertices, edges, VertexCoordinates -> vertices]
```

[image]

Unfortunately, this doesn't work for levels 2 and up. The reason is that vertices that appear where two fundamental tetrahedra intersect appear *twice* and the two copies are generated by different procedures. The procedures are algebraically equivalent but yield slightly different results numerically. We can demonstrate this by counting the number of vertices at level two:

```
g = SiPyramid[2, {1, 1, 1}];
vertices = Union[g /. Tetrahedron[{vv__}] -> vv];
vertices // Length

(* Out: 36 *)
```

If we perform the `Union` with a less stringent `SameTest`, we find that there are actually only 34 vertices:

```
Union[vertices, SameTest -> (Norm[#1 - #2] < 0.001 &)] // Length

(* Out: 34 *)
```

What we need is a tool to merge equivalent vertices. This is a common geometrical problem when precise connectivity information is needed. A similar problem arises in [this tiling problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55677) and we can use the same solution:

```
Needs["HierarchicalClustering`"]
canonicalFunction[nonCanonicalValues_List] := Module[
      {heirarchy, MyClusters, segregate, cf, clusters, 
    canonicalValues},
      Quiet[heirarchy = Agglomerate[N[nonCanonicalValues],
              DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance,
              Linkage -> "Average"]];
      segregate[Cluster[cl1_, cl2_, d_, _, _], tol_] :=   
    MyClusters[cl1, cl2] /; d > tol;
      segregate[mine_MyClusters, tol_] := 
    segregate[#, tol] & /@ mine;
      segregate[x_, _] := x;
      cf[cl_Cluster] := ClusterFlatten[cl];
      cf[x_] := {x};
      clusters = cf /@ 
     List @@ Flatten[FixedPoint[segregate[#, 10^(-12)] &,
                        MyClusters[heirarchy]]];
      canonicalValues = Chop[First /@ clusters];
      toCanonical[x_] := First[Nearest[canonicalValues][x]];
      toCanonical];
```

This `canonicalFunction` accepts a list of points and returns a function that transforms each of these individual points into a canonical representative. For example, given a tolerance of $0.1$, the list

```
{1,1.05,2,1.99,3,0.99}
```

could be transformed into

```
{1,1,2,2,3,1}
```

We can use it in your problem like so:

```
g = SiPyramid[4, {1, 1, 1}];
vertices = Union[g /. Tetrahedron[{vv__}] -> vv];
edges = Flatten[g /. Tetrahedron[vv_] :> 
  UndirectedEdge @@@ Subsets[vv, {2}]];

(* Generate the canonicalFunction *)
toCan = canonicalFunction[vertices];

(* Apply the canonicalFunction to merge vertices *)
vertices = Union[toCan /@ vertices];
edges = Map[toCan, edges, {2}];

Graph3D[vertices, edges, VertexCoordinates -> vertices]
```

[image]

One quick check is to generate the `Graph3D` without the `VertexCoordinates` option. In my experience, once you're missing some connectivity, the graph quickly flies apart. Using this technique, though, the topology looks correct:

```
Graph3D[vertices, edges]
```

[image]

Note that we've leveraged the fact that [any expression can be a vertex](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph.html#59983759). If you prefer a graph with integer indices, it is a simple matter to generate it. Here is the process for level 2.

```
g = SiPyramid[2, {1, 1, 1}];
vertices = Union[g /. Tetrahedron[{vv__}] -> vv];
edges = Flatten[
   g /. Tetrahedron[vv_] :> UndirectedEdge @@@ Subsets[vv, {2}]];

toCan = canonicalFunction[vertices];
vertices = Union[toCan /@ vertices];
edges = Map[toCan, edges, {2}];

(* Save the coordinates *)
vertexCoordinates = vertices;

(* Rename *)
globalCnt = 0;
newName[x_] := newName[x] = ++globalCnt;
vertices = newName /@ vertices;
edges = Map[newName, edges, {2}];

(* Draw with names *)
HighlightGraph[Graph3D[vertices, edges, VertexLabels -> "Name",
  VertexCoordinates -> vertexCoordinates],
Flatten[{1, 2, 3, 4,
  UndirectedEdge @@@ Subsets[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2}]}]]
```

[image]

I suppose we could really illustrate the `Graph`iness of this object by illustrating a Hamiltonian path.  Here it is at level 2. It's pretty easy to do with level 3 or 4 as well, but the exported animation is too large to upload to StackExchange.

```
{pathEdges} = FindHamiltonianCycle[g];
pathVertices = Prepend[Last /@ pathEdges, 1];
pics = Table[
   HighlightGraph[g, Join[pathVertices[[;; k]], pathEdges[[;; k]]]],
   {k, 1, Length[pathEdges]}];
Export["anim.gif", pics, "DisplayDurations" -> Append[
   Table[0.1, {Length[pathEdges] - 1}], 5],
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, is there a reason the node names are lists of points now instead of just integers?

Comment: @FEARxxx I've leveraged the fact that nodes can be *any* expression, as [proudly declared in the `Graph` documenation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph.html#28993170). It's a simple matter to convert them to integers or other simple objects, if desired. Once you get used to this approach though, it likely gives you useful structure. Each vertex name coincides with it's location in space, after all.

Comment: Is there a way of accessing each node by an integer index tho like `HighlightGraph[graph, 23]`

Comment: @FEARxxx `HighlightGraph[graph, vertices[[23]]]` *should* work but doesn't appear to. I would say that is a bug. `Graph3D[vertices, edges,VertexCoordinates -> vertices,GraphHighlight -> {vertices[[23]]}]` does work. But, again, you can always convert the graph to a graph integer vertices.

Comment: Hmm could you show how to convert it?

Comment: @FEARxxx Done..

Comment: Thanks, but this way `g = SiPyramid[1, {1, 1, 1}];` has a random node 14 (Should be 10 in total). and `g = SiPyramid[3, {1, 1, 1}];` doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43059/discussion-between-fearxxx-and-mark-mcclure).

Comment: @FEARxxx You'll need to `Clear[newName]` before re-executing with a different level since memoization was used. Should work fine then.

Answer (score 11):

There may be a simpler way to do this, but this function works for any object composed of `Tetrahedron` objects.  I also made it work for `MeshRegion` objects of dimension 3.  Expanding this to work with `Polygon`, `Line`, and `Point` objects should be straightforward.

```
tetGraph[tet3D_] := 
 With[{list = Cases[tet3D, Tetrahedron[a__] :> a]~Flatten~1},
  Graph[Range@Length@list, 
   Cases[tet3D, 
      Tetrahedron[a__] :> 
       UndirectedEdge @@@ (a[[#]] & /@ {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 
            3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}}), Infinity] /. 
     Thread[list -> Range@Length@list] // Flatten//DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort],
   VertexCoordinates -> list]
  ]
```

;
    tetGraph[mesh_MeshRegion]:= tetGraph@MeshPrimitives[mesh,3]

```
tetGraph /@ {SiPyramid[2, {1, 1, 1}], SiPyramid[3, {1, 1, 1}], 
  SiPyramid[4, {1, 1, 1}]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
SeedRandom[42];
DelaunayMesh[RandomReal[{-5, 5}, {20, 3}]]
%  // tetGraph
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks, perfect! Currently afk, but is it also scalable? Will SiPyramid[x, {1, 1, 1}]]; automatically re-adjuct for any x (i mean the graph)

Comment: It looks like some of the graph nodes overlap. If you `Graph[g, VertexLabels -> "Name"]` itll show that some verticies have the same position.

Comment: Sorry to bother again. There still seem to be dublicates left `g = tetGraph[SiPyramid[2, {1, 1, 1}]];
Graph[g, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
 VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Red, Italic, 30]]
HighlightGraph[g, 18]`. Like at iteration 2 - node 18/19  and 21/22 are overlapping.

Comment: The number of verticies is given by N_n = (d+1)(1+(d+1)^n)/2. where d is the dimension (3 in our case) and n is the fractal generation (2 in our case), so N = 34 but the graph being returned has 36.

Comment: @FEARxxx What I've written here is a general method to take a set of tetrahedra and create a `Graph` out of it.  In your case, it would be simpler if you already know the formula for the vertices to just create the `Graph` without the intermediate `Graphics3D`.  But debugging to find the duplicate vertices should be easy enough, you could use a `DeleteDuplicatesBy`, or modify the argument of `ReplaceAll`. I'm away from my PC so I can't do it, but it shouldn't be too hard....

Comment: Yes, but the thing is, they are not really duplicates, they are just extra nodes that have identical locations. If you delete one it also looses its edge.

Comment: Wonderful code.Have you seem [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/116666/21532)?I don't very content with current answer.Maybe you can give a same perfect solution?

Comment: @FEARxxx I get what you are saying, but I think the solution might be as simple as changing the original definitions of `vect[n]` to use exact numbers.  What happens if you replace every `0.5` in your code with `(1/2)`?

Comment: Perhaps if we define the geometry differently. Updated post

Comment: You can continue this [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43072/discussion-on-answer-by-jasonb-converting-graphics-geometry-to-a-graph) if you need to do further discussions @FEARxxx.

Comment: @Mark, see above as well.

Comment: @JasonB The `Round` is a vast improvement +1. I'm certain it's not as robust as a clustering approach but certainly very simple and likely to work in many cases.

Answer (score 10):

Here's my take. The idea is similar to Mark's, except that I use `ClusteringComponents[]` to identify duplicate vertices, and `VertexContract[]` to merge those vertices together:

```
tetpts = N[PolyhedronData["Tetrahedron", "VertexCoordinates"], 20];
tet = Tetrahedron[tetpts];
tr = TranslationTransform /@ (tetpts/2);
makeEdge = Function @@ {MeshCells[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[tet], 1] /. 
                        Line[l_] :> UndirectedEdge @@ Map[Slot, l]};

With[{n = 4},
     tx = Flatten[Nest[# /. Tetrahedron[pts_] :> Map[Tetrahedron[#[pts/2]] &, tr] &,
                       tet, n]];
     vc = Flatten[First /@ tx, 1]; idx = Range[4^(n + 1)];
     gt = Graph3D[idx, Flatten[makeEdge @@@ Partition[idx, 4]], VertexCoordinates -> vc];
     cl = ClusteringComponents[vc, 2 (4^n + 1), 1, Method -> "KMeans"];
     gt = Fold[VertexContract, gt, Cases[GatherBy[idx, cl[[#]] &], {_, _}]];
     gt = Graph3D[VertexList[gt], EdgeList[gt],
                  VertexCoordinates -> vc[[VertexList[gt]]], VertexSize -> Small]]
```

[image: tetrix graph]

Comment: Nice! I originally wrote my function for V5, so `ClusteringComponents` wasn't around then.

Comment: @Mark, I know; that's why I wanted to see if the current built-ins can now be used to make the code shorter. :)

Comment: Nice Solution, the vertex names are a little random tho

Comment: @FEARxxx. that's the weak point, yes. Relabeling should not take too much additional effort.

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** Using `MeshCells` and `Meshcoordinates` with `SierpinskiMesh` (Thanks: @halmir):

```
sm = SierpinskiMesh[2, 3];
vertices = Range[MeshCellCount[sm, 0]];
edges = UndirectedEdge @@@ MeshCells[sm, 1][[All, 1]];
vcoords = MeshCoordinates[sm];

Graph3D[vertices, edges, VertexCoordinates -> vcoords, 
   VertexStyle -> Red,  VertexSize -> Medium, EdgeShapeFunction -> (Tube[#,.01] &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Original post:**

```
sm = SierpinskiMesh[2, 3, 
  MeshCellShapeFunction -> {1 -> (Tube[#1, .01] &), 0->({Red,Sphere[#,.02]}&)},
  MeshCellStyle -> {{3, All}->Opacity[0],{2,All}->Opacity[0]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
edges = Cases[Show[sm], Tube[x_, _] :> (UndirectedEdge @@@ x), Infinity][[1]];
vcoords = Show[sm][[1, 1]];
vertices = Range[Length@vcoords];

Graph3D[vertices, edges, VertexCoordinates -> vcoords]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: or `Graph3D[Range[MeshCellCount[sm, 0]], UndirectedEdge @@@ MeshCells[sm, 1][[All, 1]], VertexCoordinates -> MeshCoordinates[sm]]`

Comment: Thank you @halmir. Updated the post with your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

[IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) has a convenience function for converting meshes to graphs while preserving vertex coordinates. It's as simple to use as

```
IGMeshGraph@SierpinskiMesh[2, 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The result is a weighted graph where graph edge weights correspond to mesh edge lengths. If you *don't* want weights, use

```
IGMeshGraph[SierpinskiMesh[2, 3], EdgeWeight -> None]
```

Answer (score 3):

In version 12.1, one can now directly apply the new function [`MeshConnectivityGraph[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshConnectivityGraph.html) on `SierpinskiMesh[]`:

```
MeshConnectivityGraph[SierpinskiMesh[5, 3], PlotTheme -> "LargeNetworkDefault"]
```

[image: graph with Sierpinski structure]